# Relaxed conditions on the descent directions: the angle between  and − must be acute

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors, gradient-descent

The steepest descent direction at iteration $k$ is given by
$$
\textbf{d}_k = -\textbf{g}_k = -\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})
$$
We now relax this requirement and impose the less constraining condition
$$
\forall k \geq 0, \quad -\textbf{g}_k^\top \textbf{d}_k \geq \gamma \|\textbf{g}_k\|\|\textbf{d}_k\| \quad \text{where } 0<\gamma <1 \text{ does not depend on }k
$$
In other words, the angle between $\textbf{d}_k$ and $-\textbf{g}_k$ must be **acute**. Furthermore, the cosine between these vectors must remain larger than $\gamma$ (uniformly in $k$)

**My question: Why does the angle has to be acute?**

Here is my attempt for explanation:

Recall: **law of cosine**: 
$$ 
\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{w} =  \|\textbf{v}\| \|\textbf{w}\| \cos \theta
\iff
\frac{\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{v}\| \|\textbf{w}\|} = \cos \theta 
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
-\textbf{g}_k^\top \textbf{d}_k &\geq \gamma \|\textbf{g}_k\|\|\textbf{d}_k\|\\ 
-\|\textbf{g}_k\|\|\textbf{d}_k\| \cos \theta &\geq \gamma \|\textbf{g}_k\|\|\textbf{d}_k\|\\ 
-\cos \theta &\geq \gamma \\ 
-\cos \theta &\geq 0 \\ 
\end{align*}

But it doesn't seem to help to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

By a property of the cosine

$$ \cos \langle g,d \rangle = \frac{g\cdot d}{||g||\,||d||}$$

your equation says

$$\cos \langle g,d \rangle \leq -\gamma$$

Now this seems odd to me; to have an acute angle the logical requirement should be

$$\cos \langle g,d \rangle \geq \gamma$$

I suspect there is a mistake in the text you're given. The above relationship is important because, if your objective function is of class $C^1$, then a (negative, first-order) Taylor expansion (i.e., negative gradient) at each point gives you the direction of greatest descent, so you want to have your next point within a $90$ degree range of this direction, otherwise you will be ascending.